# list view background color not set in selected view

Tags: android

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
            Log.v("Long Click", "Working");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using custom adapter or normal arraylist adaper

Comment: i am using custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an adapter and add it in order to add attributes to a listview.
[Try visiting here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

```
String [] values = {"color1","color2","color3"};
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

//rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track the position of the current selected element:

```
int defult_vaule=-1;
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            defult_vaule = position;
            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

override the getView method of your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.lout_background = (LinearLayout) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.lout_background);
    if (position == defult_vaule ) {
        // set your color     
            holder.lout_background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: my activity and custom adapters in two different classes

Comment: then use int value a public static int defult_vaule=-1; and access int value in adapter class in if(MainActivity.defult_vaule==position)

Comment: first time list long to set view background color and other times list click to set background color.list item long click to set background color successfully but list click not set background color